# Connecting Play Toggle with Video players

Tags: jquery, video, toggle, video.js

For a client I was thinking about a video player on the homepage with custom elements. I would like to connect these custom buttons with my video player. For instance if de play button is clicked, the start video. Otherwise pause video.

I commented my ideas below with //. Maybe something like that will work.

I tried several things so far, and the last thing was this, but I haven't had any success so far. Maybe one of you can help me out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$('video').each(function (index) {
    //var $(this) = videoplayer
    $('.play-toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('playvideo')) { //&& var.paused
            //var.play()
            console.log($(this))
            $(this).removeClass('playvideo');
            $(this).find('.play').css({
                "visibility": "hidden",
            });
            $(this).find('.pause').css({
                "visibility": "visible",
            });
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('playvideo');
            //var.pause()
            $(this).find('.play').css({
                "visibility": "visible",
            });
            $(this).find('.pause').css({
                "visibility": "hidden",
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$('video').each(function(i, el) {
  var p = $(el).parent();
  $('.play-toggle', p).click(function(e) {
    var button = $(this);
    console.log(button[0]);
    if (button.hasClass('playvideo')) {
      button.removeClass('playvideo');
      $('.play', button).hide();
      $('.pause', button).show();
      el.play();
      console.log($(el).attr("id") + " is playing.");
    } else {
      button.addClass('playvideo');
      $('.play', button).show();
      $('.pause', button).hide();
      el.pause();
      console.log($(el).attr("id") + " is paused.")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-player">
  <video id="video1" width="420" style="border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #222;">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML video.
  </video>
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="play-toggle playvideo">
    <span class="play">Play</span>
    <span class="pause" style="display: none;">Pause</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I switched to `.show()`/`.hide()` as this is easier to use than changing `visible`. `.each()` accepts two parameters, `index` and `element`. Using both can be a lot easier when binding functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used some parts of your code to learn from it. It worked! :-)